# Autoassign Stages and Pauses based on derivative

Tags: python

I want to autodect the changes in the slope. When the slope changes I want to assign a stage value (S1) up to that maxima. If the slope is declining again until its at its minima I want to assign a pause (P1 etc). When the data is increasing again S2 should be assigned etc.

```
Timeinsec   value
0   0.0 0.665546
1   1.0 0.662803
2   2.0 0.660060
3   3.0 0.657317
4   4.0 0.654575
... ... ...
359 359.0   1.507109
360 360.0   1.518442
361 361.0   1.531048
362 362.0   1.544033
363 363.0   1.557495


def detect_stages_and_pauses(df, col):

  df['Label'] = 0 # Initialize the Label column

  values = df[col].values
  diffs = np.diff(values)  # Calculate differences between consecutive values
  max_idx = np.argmax(values)  # Find the index of the maximum 


  for i in range(1, len(df)):
     if diffs[i - 1] > 0:
        df.at[i, 'Label'] = 'New Stage'
     elif i >= max_idx and diffs[i - 1] <= 0:  # Check for a change in slope after max_idx
        df.at[i, 'Label'] = 'Pause'
  return df,diffs
```

I have tried this so far, which does not give me the results I want. Here is the output illustration :
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You need to narrow your problem down, to support a single problem solution model.  You should use the following references on debugging your code to narrow your problem to a specific issue. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)